# New websocket on different instance of site

Tags: node.js, socket.io, connection

I have a remote control for 4 Devices running on a node server.

Each device has its own page (/1, /2, /3, /4), but they are all generated from the same html/js.

the only difference is the ip for each device, loaded from a json on the server depending on the url path.

This all works, but the problem is: i have 3 obviously wrong IPs entered for testing purposes, and one correct one. Now if i open the correct one, go back to the parent page and open the page of a device with a wrong IP, it is still shown as online and can be controlled.

I understand this like: the socket stays open across the pages and is actually not built new on every site.

how can i make sure that each subpage generates a new socket?

right now, i just have

```
socket = new io.connect();
```

in the browser.js,

```
ioServer.on('connection', function (socket) {
    //etc.
}
```

in the app.js and it works for ONE device.

Am I right to assume that I need some kind of "destroy socket if page is changed"-function?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can I see more of the actual code you're running? Socket.io connections can not persist across multiple pages if you are truly switching between pages. If you're just dynamically changing content on the same page, then that will cause problems.

Comment: sure, what exactly do you need to see?

Comment: Client and server JS? Html would be useful too

Comment: does this help? http://pastebin.com/GgNfmdPA

Comment: `I understand this like: the socket stays open across the pages and is actually not built new on every site.` - this is not true. I think the problem may be happening on your server: `device = new HyperDeck(data.device);` - what is the scope if `device`? It looks like you share the same variable across all connections.

Comment: really? i didn't know this was even possible... in my understanding this was exactly making sure that every new pageload instantiates a new device... i'm going to look into it...but how? will a root-scope var device be enough? after all that's just what i did there, isn't it? what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it, you only want to instantiate and boot a device when the device's client connects for the first time and emits 'startup'. If this is not the case, I'd probably instantiate and boot each device when the server starts.

Going with the first case, I'd store your devices in a key-value object and reuse them when needed.

```
var devices = {};

ioServer.on('connection', function (socket) {

    var client_ip_address = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
    console.log("New Connection from: " + client_ip_address);

    var device;

    socket.on('startup', function (data) {

        var deviceId = data.device;

        console.log("[INFO] startup: device " + deviceId);

        //If this device is already in devices, resuse it    
        if (deviceId in devices) {

            //Get the device from your devices object
            device = devices[deviceId];

        //Otherwise, create a new device and store it in devices
        } else {

            device = new HyperDeck(deviceId);

            //Store new device in devices object
            devices[deviceId] = device;

            device.boot();
        }

        console.log(device.id);
        console.log(device.ip);
    });

    ...
```

Comment: instantiating all devices on server startup sounds like an even better idea... how would i connect to the particular device then? ie device 1 on /1 ? the whole code will have to be changed according to device+id , or not? can all pages still be served with the same html?

Comment: it works! i can only control one device at a time (because there is always just one active object at a time, but i think that's enough for now :) thanks!